# Pc is squeaking while playing Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc, technical-issues

Every time I open Minecraft my computer starts squeaking a little. Did anyone of you have a similar problem or have a clue what could be the problem? This kind of behavior only occurs when playing Minecraft, all the other games run without any problems.

Comment: What do you mean by squeaking? Is it some sound that comes out the speakers, or some other mechanical noise?

Comment: I changed the FPS in Minecraft and it stopped. think it was cause i had 600+ FPS ingame

Comment: So maybe Minecraft is using too much CPU or video card resources that their fan is kicking in and making the noises. But then you would notice a lag (several seconds to a minute) between starting Minecraft and hearing the noise, because it takes a little time for the CPU and GPU to heat up. Another source of noise (that comes out on the speakers) can be the computer monitor.

Comment: Sounds like coil whine. Some GPU's get that at very high framerates. Limit your framerate or use VSync.

Answer (score 7):

Since this only happens when playing Minecraft, this is probably because your CPU is being overloaded when the game is running. Try minimising the amount of other applications you have open or making the game use less processing power. This can be achieved in several ways:

- Making the FPS lower
- Turn fancy graphics to fast
- Set render distance low (< 5)
- Minimise the amount of resource packs/any mods you might have
- Running in a window instead of fullscreen
- Turn on V-sync
- Turn the GUI scale down to small

*Note: This is not an exhaustive list, just a few ways that work.*

Answer (score 0):

Try turning the frame rate limit down, since you said you had it at 600+ it may be caused by the computer drawing too much power and the power supply coils are starting to whine because of high energy draw.

Also turn on V-Sync and keep the max frame rate to about 120FPS to keep the quality as good as it can be.

Comment: This isn't so crazy: capacity squeal, coil whine, transformer vibration, and Voltage Regulator squeak are all Things(tm)

Comment: Nothing new on what has already been posted, however

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

- Turn Graphics to 'Fast'
- Set your Render Down
- Turn your FPS Limit down
- Close Background processes (If Possible)
- Turn off any Mods you may have
- Minimise the Window (Fullscreen > Windowed)
- Set GUI Scale to 'Small'

Answer (score -1):

Turn your FPS limit off max. Your computer is working as hard as it can to give you the best FPS that it can instead of limiting it.